# Anti forgery system on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I'm putting following code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    }
```

the

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

part is thrownig following exception:

*The provided identity of type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity' is marked IsAuthenticated = true but does not have a value for Name. By default, the anti-forgery system requires that all authenticated identities have a unique Name. If it is not possible to provide a unique Name for this identity, consider setting the static property AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider to an instance of a type that can provide some form of unique identifier for the current user.*

I've checked many examples and tried to search the web, but I cannot find any explanation. I would like to know why this error happens to me? And how to solve it to use antiforgery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's telling you that it won't work because despite being logged in, `Membership.GetUser().UserName` is not providing a name that can be used for hashing.

So your real problem is, "How come my ***logged in*** user doesn't have a username?"

Comment: My real problem is "How come my user is logged in even though I've just started debugging for the first time?"

Answer (score 6):

There can be some cases when logged in user doesn't have Identity.Name set (in my case I have to integrate my app with some crazy log-in system). Then there are two ways around:

1) unsecure - all users will be treated the same way by antiforgery system regardless of their auth status

```
// System.Web.WebPages.dll
using System.Web.Helpers;

// not a production solution
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
  protected void Application_Start() {
    AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true;
  }
}
```

2) secure - provide your own (custom) way how you distinguish your users

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;

public class ContoscoAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider : IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider {
  public string GetAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context) {
    if (context == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }

    var contoscoContext = new ContoscoHttpContext(context);
    int userID = contoscoContext.GetUserID().GetValueOrDefault();
    return Convert.ToString(userID, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }

  public bool ValidateAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context, string additionalData) {
    string data = GetAdditionalData(context);
    return string.Compare(data, additionalData, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0;
  }
}


public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
  protected void Application_Start() {
    AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider = 
      new ContoscoAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider(); 
  }
}
```

where `ContoscoHttpContext` is class that returns UserID (or any unique user token) based on current context (i.e. `HttpContextBase`):

```
public class ContoscoHttpContext {
  private HttpContextBase _context;
  public ContoscoHttpContext(HttpContextBase context) {
    _context = context;
  }
  public int? GetUserID() {
    // TODO: provide your own implementation how to get user id
    // based on HttpContextBase stored in _context
    // in my case it was something like 
    // return ((ContoscoPrincipal)_context.User).UserID;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks (with "s").

Comment: What does ContoscoHttpContext do?

Comment: @slolife - updated; I hope it now does explain the meaning of ContoscoHttpContext. Basically its a made-up class that returns UserID based on current context.