# Custom login with mvc messing up with the login partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

So I've set up a custom login in my MVC application which appears to work...

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.Login())
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email address or password.");
        }
    }

    // If execution got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

public class User
{
    public bool Login()
    {
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress == EmailAddress);

        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("User not found.");
        }
        else
        {
            // validates whether or not the password on the user record
            // that was retrieved by the query matches the password entered at login
            return Hashing.ValidatePassword(Password, user.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there's some conflict between it and the default `_LoginPartial.cshtml` View (which looks like below):

```
@model LoganMVC.Models.User
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", new { User.Identity.Name })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </text>
} else {
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

The ArgumentNullException highlights this line...

> Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", new { User.Identity.Name })!

Saying...

> Value cannot be null or empty.

It's clear that the value that cannot be null or empty is `User.Identity.Name`, but what isn't clear is WHY `IsAuthenticated` is true to begin with. This is Forms Authentication and, as far as the software is aware (because I killed the debug server, closed the solution and started debugging fresh again), the application has never run before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've been bashing my head against various hard surfaces trying to get this one figured out and eventually did.

After looking at the errors I was initially getting:

> Value cannot be null or empty.

And then later

> The provided identity of type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity' is marked IsAuthenticated = true but does not have a value for Name. By default, the anti-forgery system requires that all authenticated identities have a unique Name. If it is not possible to provide a unique Name for this identity, consider setting the static property AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider to an instance of a type that can provide some form of unique identifier for the current user.

Were fairly simple fixes.

First off, I had initially set my login cookie to persist. This means that it wouldn't be deleted when the browser is closed and would not expire either. While this did not cause the `Value cannot be null or empty` error, it was contributory in that the site was finding it and assuming a user had authenticated.

**FIX**
To fix this, I simply cleared cookies from my browser set the cookie's persist to false. This allowed me to focus more on the actual problem.

*Value cannot be null or empty*

This problem was actually not as complicated as I thought. When I started taking a closer look at things, I noticed that there was an error in the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.Login())
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email address or password.");
        }
    }

    // If execution got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

This post captures an instance of my User model from the form (which is the login form so only EmailAddress and Password values are included). It also uses the Username value from this model (which is null) to set the Authentication Cookie.

I changed my `.Login()` method to a function that returns a User if the email address is found and the stored hash matches a hash of the password entered for the login.

The code, thus, changed to the following (this is only the key point of the change)

```
// Account.Login Post
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = model.Login(model.EmailAddress);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email address or password.");
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, true);
    // create session variables n such
}

// User.Login
public User Login(string EmailAddress
{
    var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress == Email);

    if (user == null)
        throw new Exception("User not found.");

    if (Hashing.ValidatePassword(Password, user.Password))
        return user;

    return null; // if we got here, something went wrong
}
```

Once I'd fixed this, I got another problem later. Some issue to do with the Anti-Forgery system.

While not a solution, I managed a workaround and commented out the following line from my _LoginPartial View:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

I had concerns about security but I figured that Forms Auth on a basic asp.net website with a hashed and salted password has been sufficient for quite a number of years, so I shouldn't have any issues with it here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss something. In your controller `Account` you have an Action:

```
  public ActionResult Manage(string name) // I presume name
 {
  ....
 }
```

Then your line should be:

```
  Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", new { name=User.Identity.Name })!
```

The anonymous object which is routeValues
It's n object that contains the parameters for a route. The parameters are retrieved through reflection by examining the properties of the object. The object is typically created by using object initializer syntax.(Definition taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)) And it should be well formatted.

I hope it will solve the problem otherwise you have to check if the User.Identity is different of `null`.
I have noticed also somthing else in this line:

```
 var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress == EmailAddress);
```

Where comes from the `EmailAddress` after `==`?
You should provide a parameter to you `Login` method to replace your second `EmailAddress`.

```
   public bool Login(string emailAddress)
   {
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress == emailAddress);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ValidationException("User not found.");
    }
    else
    {
        // validates whether or not the password on the user record
        // that was retrieved by the query matches the password entered at login
        return Hashing.ValidatePassword(Password, user.Password);
    }
```

Comment: I understand what you mean about the email address, but can you elaborate more on the first part?

Comment: My Login Post method passes `User user` as the first part so that passes through an instance of my User model which has the the email address. That's where the email address for the query comes from. At this point, I'm thinking I need to check if User.Identity is null, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Now I'm having trouble with the anti-forgery system... `The provided identity of type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity' is marked IsAuthenticated = true but does not have a value for Name. By default, the anti-forgery system requires that all authenticated identities have a unique Name. If it is not possible to provide a unique Name for this identity, consider setting the static property AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider to an instance of a type that can provide some form of unique identifier for the current user.`

Comment: Read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12796319/3383479) you will find thsolution